# two sided test convenience and p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, p-value

I have a serious doubt about one characteristic of the two-sided test:

Suppose we have a random variable: $
X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})
    $
where $\sigma = 0.4$ but $\mu$ is unknown.

We want to test:

$H_{0}: \mu = 3$ against $H_{1}: \mu > 3$

The thing is, that this random variable $X$ is a Proportion. Is the concentration of some mineral in a food. So it would be more accurate to establish: $H_{0}: \mu = 3$% against $H_{1}: \mu > 3$%

So, if from a random sample of $n=64$ we get a sample mean $\bar{x} = 3,07$%

**(a)** If we use a significance level of $\alpha = 5$%, we don't reject the $H_{0}$.

**(b)** The p-value of this test is $0,08$.

**(c)** If we use a different $H_{1}: \mu \neq 3$  would the p-value be bigger now (lower or equal)?? How can I see that with a graph?

**(d)** In the context of this problem, why is a one-sided test more appropriate than a two-sided test??

Comment: What are your thoughts on how the current p-value of 0.08 is calculated?

Comment: If $X$ represents a proportion (between 0 to 1), why do you assume that $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$? This assumption even allows $X$ to be negative.

Comment: The problem states that $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, i didn't assume anything.